# pass different parameters to different task instances

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I'm running an ECS task and want to scale up the count to 2. One of the two instances is supposed to be a read-only instance and i want to pass it an env var to let it know that it should not execute certain bits of code.

How can I pass that env var just to the one instance but not the other?

Comment: Are they part of the same ECS service, or different services?

Comment: @marcin same service

Comment: A service runs instances of same task. You can't customize individual tasks. You have to use different services, or come out with custom solution for what you want to do.

Comment: I settled for leader election. Only the leader will be allowed to execute parts of the code.